# How to show div as per object value status in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5

I have an object which is updated with some conditions as per this object status I want to show/hide div.

Condition: Div will show when first time get true from obj.key

For example

```
obj: any = {
  a: false,
  b: false,
  c: true
};      
<div class="hide">a</div> 
<div class="hide">b</div>
<div class="show">c</div>
```

Example 2

```
 obj: any = {
  a: false,
  b: true,
  c: true
 };

<div class="hide">a</div> 
<div class="show">b</div>
<div class="hide">c</div>
```

Comment: Use `*ngIf="a"` or example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  obj: any = {
    a: false,
    b: true,
    c: true
  };

  values = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    let alreadyAchieved = false;
    for(let key in this.obj) {
      if(this.obj[key] && !alreadyAchieved) {
        alreadyAchieved = true;
        let value = { key: key, value: this.obj[key] };
        this.values.push(value);
      } else {
        let value = { key: key, value: false };
        this.values.push(false);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

And in the template:

```
<div *ngFor="let val of values">
  <div *ngIf="val.value">
    {{ val.key }}
  </div>
</div>
```

This way, you would be able to extend it to more than just three keys in the object.

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-div-visibility)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show html with specific hide/show classes defined in css, then this should work,

```
obj: any = {
  a: false,
  b: true,
  c: true
 };
<div [ngClass]="[obj.a ? 'show' : 'hide']">a</div>
<div [ngClass]="[obj.b ? 'show' : 'hide']">b</div>
<div [ngClass]="[obj.c ? 'show' : 'hide']">c</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, dince2 is right! if you want to check the boolean values, you can use it like this:

```
 obj: any = {
  a: false,
  b: true,
  c: true
 };

<div *ngIf = "obj.a">a</div>
```

or you can use it like this :

```
<div [ngClass] = "[obj.a ? 'show' : 'hide']">a</div>
```